# How to access iPod media library?

Tags: ios, cordova, media, picker

I'm trying to access the iPod Media Library from within PhoneGap (Cordova) to be able to pick a song from the user's library for us, preferably copying it to the documents folder. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

I'm thinking I will have to write it natively in Objective-C and create a JS plugin to interface with it?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested, I manage to solve this by creating my own Cordova plugin to display the iPod Media Picker and once they user selects a song it converts and copies the song to the apps document folder and returns the filename as well as album, artist, duration etc back to the JS for use.

I will be uploading to GitHub shortly for anyone that wants it.

Comment: I'm really interested! Did you already made it available in GitHub?

Comment: +1, please let me know when this is available. I'd like to add this feature in.

Comment: Would also like to take a look at this plugin :)

Comment: Can you share the URL please? Thanks!

Comment: Hey I'd be interested in this. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I have created the plugin, take a look if it helps -

[iOS Audio Picker](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/ios-audio-picker)